# How to keep current file if the request doesn't have file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have this function that will update the data as showing below:

```
public function update(Request $request, OutstandingPayment $outstandingPayment)
{


    $request->validate([
           'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
           'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => 'required|string',
           'payment_voucher_date' => 'required|string',
        ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file_path = $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'), $file_name);
        $request->payment_voucher_supporting_doc = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->path = '/storage/' . $file_path;
    }

    $postData = [
        'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => $request->payment_voucher_file_ref_no,
        'payment_voucher_date' => $request->payment_voucher_date,
        'payment_voucher_supporting_doc' => $request->payment_voucher_supporting_doc,
        'path' => $request->path,
    ];

    $outstandingPayment->update($postData);

}
```

The above function is working fine but only if i uploaded new file

Note: "File" is -> "file" is "payment_voucher_supporting_doc" i am passing it in the request as "file" and place it in "payment_voucher_supporting_doc"

But in my case now, if there are no changes on "file" i want the current one to stay the same

I tried to add "else" if there is no file and assign "payment_voucher_supporting_doc" to outstandingPayment->payment_voucher_supporting_doc" but the response show that still "file" is required

How can i achieve that?

Comment: File is required because -> `$request->validate([ 'file' => 'required`,.......`

Comment: i commented it and tried `outstandingPayment->payment_voucher_supporting_doc` and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't find best ways on your code about
whether your upload file
had changed or not.

For example, can you try to set `guard method` before update your file?
like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, OutstandingPayment $outstandingPayment)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
            'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => 'required|string',
            'payment_voucher_date' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        // all validate has passed,so please check whether your file contents has changed or not
        // file name change is all contents has changed?
        $isSameFile = ( // true or false
            $request->hasFile('file')
            &&
            preg_match('/'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName().'/',$outstandingPayment->payment_voucher_supporting_doc)
        );

        // if isSameFile is true, don't need to update file status?
        if ($isSameFile) return;

        // if you don't need above guard method, process is under following.
        $file_name = ($isSameFile) ? $outstandingPayment->payment_voucher_supporting_doc : time() . '_' . $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->payment_voucher_supporting_doc = $file_name;
        $request->path = ($isSameFile) ? $outstandingPayment->path : '/storage/' . $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'), $file_name);

        // if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        //     $file_name = time() . '_' . $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        //     $file_path = $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'), $file_name);
        //     $request->payment_voucher_supporting_doc = time() . '_' . $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        //     $request->path = '/storage/' . $file_path;
        // }

        $postData = [
            'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => $request->payment_voucher_file_ref_no,
            'payment_voucher_date' => $request->payment_voucher_date, // is this belong with upload action ?
            'payment_voucher_supporting_doc' => $request->payment_voucher_supporting_doc,
            'path' => $request->path,
        ];

        $outstandingPayment->update($postData);
    }
```

how do you check file is newest or not ? name or contents detail?

ps: you use `time()` method some places. if your function
processing speed is slow, your file name will be different like 160000_hoge.png and 160003_hoge.png.
so, I recommend to fix that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your validation `nullable` and then put every field that you want update with file in if block:

a hypothetical example(because your code is so long and I use mobile to type this answer): I want update user's profile and name but i want profile will be update if there is a picture in my request:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user){
 $request->validate([
'picture' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg',
'name'=>'required|max:255'
]);
if($request->hasFile('picture')){
/* Upload file */
$user->profile= 'uploaded picture path';
}
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->update();

}
```

In my example, profile field will be updated if I upload a picture, otherwise just user's name will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Yikes. but your file is required because you have it as required in your validation. Also this can be cleaned up quite a bit like using a form request object for the validation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation

```
public function update(Request $request, OutstandingPayment $outstandingPayment) {

   $request->validate([
    'file' =>'nullable|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
    'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => 'required|string',
    'payment_voucher_date' => 'required|string',
]);

$data = [ 
  'payment_voucher_file_ref_no' => $request->payment_voucher_file_ref_no,\
  'payment_voucher_date' => $request->payment_voucher_date,
];

if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('file')->move(
        public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'),
        $name
    );

    $data['payment_voucher_supporting_doc'] = $path;
    $data['path'] = "storage/$path";
}

    $outstandingPayment->update($data);
}
```